# Javascript replacing with just one replacing option

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I am currently sanitizing code, and I have this JS expression which replaces bad code as:

```
str.replace(/[\W_,.]/g,'-').toLowerCase();
```

If a user inputed this `a+ñ4a_i4a` my code JS  replaces to => `a--4a-i4a` the idea is good but not with so many `- - - -`. It should replace all the hyphens with just one if they **are together**.

So the code should output `a-4a-i4a`

Any idea on how to replace occurrences of the same multiple character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the character class `[\W_,.]+` to match all the consecutive matches, and then replace with a single `-`

```js
console.log("a+ñ4a_i4a".replace(/[\W_,.]+/g, '-').toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Please note the ``+/g`` on the code, that solves everything. Salute @The fourth bird